# VHD to physical drive with no host os

Tags: windows, hyper-v, boot, vhd

I have installed windows server 2012 r2 with exchange 2010 on it on virtual machine (Hyper-V)
I need to move VHD to physical drive.
I know that windows can boot VHD images, but i need to move OS exactly to physical drive, not using VHD.
Is it possilbe?
Thx for all answers

Answer (score 0):

Acronis Backup Advanced can do that.
It can transfer by scheme - physical-virtual, virtual-physical, virtual-virtual, physical-physical